# Class implements two interfaces with the same method but different checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception

In the book "Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805 A Comprehensive OCPJP 7 Certification Guide" by S G Ganesh and Tushar Sharma, it's stated

> "if a method is declared in 2 or more interfaces, and if that method
>   declares to throw different exceptions in the throws clause, the
>   implementation should list all these exceptions" (page 347)

Well, then I've tried this

```
public interface I1 {
    public void x() throws I1Exception;
}

public interface I2 {
    public void x() throws I2Exception;
}

public class I1Exception extends Exception {
}

public class I2Exception extends Exception {
}

public class Sample implements I1, I2{

    @Override
    public void x() throws I2Exception {
        throw new I2Exception();        
    }

    @Override
    public void x() throws I1Exception {
        throw new I1Exception();        
    }

}
```

Of course, the exception is not part of the method signature, so the compiler complains that the second method is duplicated.

On the other hand

```
@Override
public void x() throws I1Exception, I2Exception {
    throw new I1Exception();        
}
```

Is not compatible with both interfaces because it declares more checked exceptions than any one of the methods of each interface, taken separately.

**This means that I don't understood what the book says or does that mean the book statement is innacurate?**

Comment: @Milaci I disagree. The question is not about two same methods from different interfaces (if it was I could compile my code) but different methods only by a checked interface. Believe me, I've spend 10 minutes looking for similar questions in SO ;-)

Comment: I think the book is wrong. This can't work.

Comment: If you try to make `public void x() throws Exception` and inside it to throw an Exception that you want? p.s:`throw new I1Exception();`

Comment: @Milaci I guess I could only do that if I change both interfaces first ;-) good point

Comment: Exception is the parent of all Exception. You substitute both I1Exception, I2Exception with it!

Comment: A very good question, by the way.

Comment: Please accept Nandana's answer instead of mine as he provided the normative reference and full code examples.

Comment: sounds fair. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That specific sentence of the book seems to be incorrect. The Java Language Specification has more reasonable clause explaining this issue (which I think is the part referred by the book).

> [When interfaces are involved, more than one method declaration may be overridden by a single overriding declaration. In this case, the overriding declaration must have a throws clause that is compatible with all the overridden declarations (§9.4.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2).

So in this case, one that is compatible with both declarations would be

```
@Override
public void x() {
}
```

In both declarations had common exceptions they could have included in the declaration.

```
interface I1 {
    public void x() throws I1Exception, I2Exception;
}

interface I2 {
    public void x() throws I2Exception;
}
```

then

```
@Override
public void x() throws I2Exception {
}
```

Or alternatively in your example, if you had something like

```
class I1Exception extends I2Exception {
}

class I2Exception extends Exception {
}
```

Then a compatible method declaration could be written as

```
@Override
public void x() throws I1Exception {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

After giving it a second thought, I think the intention of the book was to say that you have to satisfy both interfaces at the same time.

So the method should throw (roughly speaking) an intersection of sets of exceptions of both methods. If these sets don't intersect then the method can't throw anything. So this:

```
@Override
public void x() {
}
```

Is OK for both interfaces.

(It's a bit more complicated because of inheritance, but you get the idea.)

So from my point of view

> "if a method is declared in 2 or more interfaces, and if that method
>   declares to throw different exceptions in the throws clause, the
>   implementation should list all these exceptions" (page 347)

can't be correct because it does not work in practice. You (in most cases) can't list all of these exceptions in an implementation. There are exceptions like unchecked exceptions or identical/compatible sets of exceptions.

However I could not find normative reference in JLS for this.

Comment: `the implementation should list all these exceptions` doesn't sound like the book meant to say `an intersection of sets of exceptions`.

Comment: You're sure right. Therefor I say, this looks incorrect in the book but it was probably a good intention like "consider everything".

Answer (score 1):

I think that the book states that you can choose which method you want to implement, but can't implement both of them (didn't try it, but that's how I would understand it).

`the implementation should list all these exceptions` probably means all exceptions that one method declares in the `throws` clause.

Comment: Well, of course this is what the book says. The problem is that it can't work for different checked exceptions.

Comment: @lexicore The question at the end is `This means that I don't understood what the book says or does that mean the book statement is innacurate?`, and not how to make it work. The book statement is accurate, my answer hopefully clarifies what it was suppose to mean.

Comment: "You should do something" which does not work in practice is not an accurate statement in a programming language certification guide, if you ask me.

Comment: I think `all these exceptions` part is making a confusion. If you think it means 'all exceptions from both methods', of course it is wrong. If you understood it as 'all exceptions one of these methods throws, the one you want to implement', then it is a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error is having two methods in the same class with the same name that get no parameters.
In java you can have different methods with the same name only if they get different parameters: for example

```
public int i (int a);
public int i ();
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Of course it is wrong to have two methods with the same name and same parameters. The question is about methods from two different interfaces, same name, same parameters but different exceptions.

Comment: But the compiler complains a duplicated method because of that declaration, not because of exceptions.

Comment: This is the first option the OP investigates. Which is obviously invalid. The second option is about one method with different exceptions.

Comment: "Of course, the exception is not part of the method signature, so the compiler complains that the second method is duplicated." In my opinion this means he thinks the compiler raises the error because of the method signature that does not include the exception, not for the double declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> The set of checked exceptions that a method can throw is the
>   intersection of the sets of checked exceptions that it is declared to
>   throw in all applicable types, not the union.
>   As a result, the x() on an object can’t throw any checked exceptions at all and is permitted.

```
@Override
public void x() {
}
```

It illustrates the
**interaction of multiple inherited throws clauses, which reduces rather than
increases the number of exceptions that a method is permitted to throw.** This don’t generally cause subtle bugs, but they can be a bit surprising the first time you see them.